# Percentage format does not changes to float - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, percentage

I'm having a problem with converting my data to fro dataframe to percentage format and keep it as a float.

I prepared a simple code thats reflects the code from my actual project:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)

cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.4%}'.format(n))
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

In my actual project I need to choose ONLY columns that contain specific string and do some calculation on their values. At the end I have to change the formatting to percentage with 4 decimal places. Eventhough I use `astype(float)`my values are still `str`.
Consequently, when I save dataframe to excel file, values are pasted as text and not as number.
In addition, while creating a line chart from this dataframe, I get an error 'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.

Please advise on how to succefully convert data to percentage format and keep it as a float in order to get accurate paste in excel file and creating a line chart with matplotlib.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you are using .format after .astype(float). The code first converts the values to float but then as format is a str function, it gets converted to string with 4 decimal places. You can try doing the following:

```
df[col] = df[col].map(lambda n: '{:.4%}'.format(n)).astype(float)
```

OR

You can try dividing your code line into two parts inside the for loop:

```
df[col] = df[col].map(lambda n: '{:.4%}'.format(n))
df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this option before and received error: "could not convert string to float"